# timestamp is not saving in database when use strtotime in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, timestamp

i have a problem when i try to insert a time in my database using mysql:

The database is storing the date wrongly as you can see:

[image]

The column type is TIMESTAMP

[image]

In my code (i am using PHP with codeigniter 4 for this), i have a string date, but the type of the field which is saving the date is TIMESTAMP

```
$fecha = strtotime($pedido['fecha_creacion']);   //Get the date from string and converting it to timestamp

$dbventor->query("INSERT INTO tfacpeda(FECHA)VALUES ($fecha));   //Insert to database, but wrongly
```

The variable fecha contains a date string like this: `"2022-10-07 15:03:10"`

can you help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: `$fecha = strtotime($pedido['fecha_creacion']);` gives a timestamp and not a date string!

Comment: I know, and that is why i am trying to storing it to the database, the field type of the database is in timestamp not date string, so i have to convert from date string to timestamp

Comment: @LuisBermúdez The naming of the column in MySQL is somewhat misleading; it's called a `TIMESTAMP` field, but it still expects a date formatted like `2022-10-07 15:03:10`, not a numeric timestamp. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html; the difference is in how the data is stored behind the scenes.

Comment: Format of timestamp in a DB column is different. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: that's interesting and i didn't know that, let me see that doc :)

Comment: The English word "timestamp" just refers to a date and time, it doesn't imply any specific format. `strtotime()` produces a Unix time (which is an integer number) but your database column expects a text in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. For good or bad, it isn't safe to make assumptions based on words, you need to actually check documentation :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but you say that i can store the date string without any issues? because it tolds me an error like this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:56:17) at line 1"

Comment: @LuisBermúdez, put the date in quotes `'2022-10-07 14:56:17'`

Comment: That's SQL injection, which is a different subject. Doesn't your framework implement prepared statements and bind parameters to run SQL queries?

Comment: Thanks a lot problem solved, i will mark my answer, thanks for help me to understand the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

the issue comes because a confusion, the timestamp doesn't have to be treated in a different way, because the database is expecting to receive a date string

```
$fecha = $pedido['fecha_creacion'];

$dbventor->query("INSERT INTO tfacpeda(FECHA)VALUES ('$fecha'));   //Note the quotes at the variable '$fecha'
```